# Unable write data into .xslb file

Tags: excel, vb.net

Below is the line of code I am using to enter values in excel cells but code is making blank entries and file type is .xlsb

```
sWebADIFilePath="C:\Users\uk1346\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles\Book1((Unsaved-306660471733269083)).xlsb"

Set objExcelbook2 = GetObject(sWebADIFilePath)

Set objExcelsheet2 = objExcelbook2.Worksheets(sWebADISheetName)

objExcelsheet2.Cells(8,5) = sLedgerJ

objExcelsheet2.Cells(9,5) = sCategoryJ

objExcelsheet2.Cells(10,5) = sCurrencyJ

objExcelsheet2.Cells(11,5) = sAccountingDateJ

objExcelsheet2.Cells(12,5) = sJournalName

objExcelsheet2.Cells(13,5) = sJournalDescription
```

Screenshot for the application:
[image]

Comment: Couldn't you use `xlsx`?  Also, why are you saving to a system folder? (er, temp name, etc)

Comment: Hi Ahlee,The excel is generated from an application and if we are saving it its behaviour is changing and functionality is not as expected.